# Trying to recreate a page in Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

There's a page from the Chocolate Emporium website, which uses a Shopify checkout that I really want to emulate.  However the website I'm emulating it on uses Bootstrap3, which i think is what's making it difficult.

Okay so this is the checkout page that I like:
https://the-chocolate-emporium.com/cart
(You'll have to add something to your cart in order to view the checkout page, sorry.  This is not an advert for their site I just like the checkout process)

So I've created this codepen, which is basically the layout of my current site:

https://codepen.io/chud37/pen/jOVmrQK

So on the Chocolate Emporium checkout page, there is an :after psuedo element on the right hand side column, that has CSS that looks like this:

```
content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #f6f2e7;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #dddad0 inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #dddad0 inset;
    background-position: left top;
    width: 300%;
```

So really the big problem is the `width:300%`.  It is causing the page to be super wide and therefore the horizontal scroll bar to show.  However on the Chocolate Emporium website the scrollbar isnt showing, and I can't figure out why. The biggest difference is they use flexbox all over the place, and boostrap3 doesnt.

Is it possible to have the same design in bootstrap3 without the horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why exactly do you want to copy everything where you want to change to your own taste and creativity? Maybe you can design something better. I changed your source a bit. I do not know if it is desirable for you or not

css

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body
{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.left-side,
.right-side {padding: 50px;}

.right-side {height: 100vh;}
.right-side:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #f6f2e7;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #dddad0 inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #dddad0 inset;
    background-position: left top;
    width: 100%;

}
```

html

```
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="content">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="left-side col-xs-7">
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas feugiat euismod orci, nec auctor sapien ultricies eu. Mauris rhoncus turpis leo, et rutrum leo congue bibendum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ultricies sed ex a imperdiet. Fusce feugiat nibh nunc, eget dapibus felis tempus id. Duis at lorem interdum, commodo ante sed, efficitur justo. Quisque semper sit amet purus ut maximus. Suspendisse fringilla vitae tellus eu viverra. Nam dolor ante, scelerisque id enim id, pulvinar maximus sem. Vivamus tristique erat non leo ultrices maximus. Sed vitae nunc auctor, placerat nunc et, pharetra ipsum. Sed a pretium nulla. Aenean felis orci, dictum at nibh quis, tristique egestas lacus.

    Aliquam ornare tellus et tincidunt aliquet. Fusce at felis eleifend sem mattis sodales suscipit in orci. Donec in cursus neque. Duis in odio malesuada, eleifend risus vel, ultrices erat. Phasellus vel mi nec sem rhoncus malesuada. Aenean tristique sit amet ante id suscipit. Mauris non viverra nunc. Etiam sagittis lectus sed felis elementum, at vulputate lorem feugiat.
            </div>
            <div class="right-side col-xs-5">
              
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas feugiat euismod orci, nec auctor sapien ultricies eu. Mauris rhoncus turpis leo, et rutrum leo congue bibendum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ultricies sed ex a imperdiet. Fusce feugiat nibh nunc, eget dapibus felis tempus id. Duis at lorem interdum, commodo ante sed, efficitur justo. Quisque semper sit amet purus ut maximus. Suspendisse fringilla vitae tellus eu viverra. Nam dolor ante, scelerisque id enim id, pulvinar maximus sem. Vivamus tristique erat non leo ultrices maximus. Sed vitae nunc auctor, placerat nunc et, pharetra ipsum. Sed a pretium nulla. Aenean felis orci, dictum at nibh quis, tristique egestas lacus.

    Aliquam ornare tellus et tincidunt aliquet. Fusce at felis eleifend sem mattis sodales suscipit in orci. Donec in cursus neque. Duis in odio malesuada, eleifend risus vel, ultrices erat. Phasellus vel mi nec sem rhoncus malesuada. Aenean tristique sit amet ante id suscipit. Mauris non viverra nunc. Etiam sagittis lectus sed felis elementum, at vulputate lorem feugiat.
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Body Overflow! Thank you, I knew there was a simple solution.